# vi not recognizing scrolling, scrolls terminal instead

Tags: vim

I have an instance of vi on a remote server that is not behaving like it used to, and I'm not sure what made this happen.

On my local shell, (and the remote server before this started happening), if I scroll with my mouse/touchpad, it would navigate the cursor within vim. I have checked my .vimrc and there's nothing in it relating to the mouse, and I did not make any changes to it before this issue started.

The only thing I can think of is that a few weeks ago, I was trying to figure out how I could split two files in the same vi instance so I could yank from one file to another, and I tried some : commands that I didn't really understand (didn't get any productive results). And also, I ran tmux once, but I don't think there are any . files that are applying unwanted settings (not sure).

I can't find anything to check the vi settings being applied, but I know that my .vimrc is working, and it's not anything in there (if I comment everything out it still behaves this way).

I just want my vi to respond the same way.

Describing the problem more exactly:
If I scroll, the cursor doesn't move, instead it scrolls on the terminal window, and it shows the previous bash commands instead of scrolling the file being edited. If I navigate using vim keys, it still works.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly, I discovered that it actually had to do with the a specific terminal instance that was causing the issue. Closed it, opened a new one, no issue now. If anyone has any insight on why this could've been, I'd love to know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

.vimrc applies to vim not vi, doesn't it ?

the problem of scrolling might come from your terminal emulator as well.

I usually use embedded terminal in VS code which is not ideal (since it's not made for administration ...) but it's practical with keybinds to jump from one window to another, copy paste ...
I know some colleagues who use, mobaXterm or mremoteNG on windows.

I know I should give a go to Terminator, but it's on linux only and I don't want to run a local vm just for that.

Comment: .vimrc does apply to vi as well, at least on the remote linux server I'm on. 

Was just using the default for macOS. Turned out to be a terminal specific issue. I've realized that the issue seems to come up when my laptop goes to sleep while still ssh'd to the remote server. On occasion, I don't get the "broken pipe" error that disconnects me, and if I resume my session, this bug occurs sometimes. 
Always fixed upon resetting that terminal instance or starting a new one though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the vi editor is not yet install on the PC.This usually happened for newly installed Ubuntu OS or other virtual box OS. The below code resolved the issue 100% for me in a very easy way.
This resolve the issue:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Thanks